# Set values in a Pandas MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I want to swaplevel and set values after a selection.

In the example I would like to set 'c1' columns to 1 inplace but it seems its not working as I expected.

EDITED: Not clearly expressed: I want to set 1 to the values of the C1 columns. Not to rename C1.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
mix = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a1','b1','c1'),('a1','b2','c1'),('a1','b3','c2')])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,3)),columns=mix)
print(df)
df.swaplevel(0,2,axis=1).loc[:,'c1']=1  
print(df)

Output
        a1          
        b1   b2   b3
        c1   c1   c2
    0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    1  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2  0.0  0.0  0.0

' FutureWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt \nto set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array. \nTo retain the old behavior, use either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, \nif columns are non-unique, `df.isetitem(i, newvals)`\n'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mess up with your Index, use [advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html):

```
df.loc[:, (slice(None), slice(None), 'c1')] = 1
```

Or:

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'c1']] = 1
```

In place modified `df`:

```
  a1        
  b1 b2   b3
  c1 c1   c2
0  1  1  0.0
1  1  1  0.0
2  1  1  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

### `swaplevel` + `assign`

```
df.swaplevel(0, 2, axis=1).assign(c1=1)
```

Result

```
  c1      c2
  b1 b2   b3
  a1 a1   a1
0  1  1  0.0
1  1  1  0.0
2  1  1  0.0
```

Comment: I want to assign 1 to values. Not to the name of the columns. Sorry if it was not clear

Comment: Np. Check the edit.

Comment: It works, however assign method says: Returns a new object with all original columns in addition to new ones.  So, in a big dataframe, it seems it's moving data between the old dataframe and the new one... Is it ? Is possible to wirte data "inplace" ?